# I need a format of code that only counts odd lines

Tags: batch-file

test_title.bat

```
:GET_DOWNLOADS
set Counter=-1
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in ('type version.txt') do (
set /a Counter+=2
set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
)
if exist version.txt del version.txt
exit /b

:list_files
call :GET_DOWNLOADS
For /L %%C in (1,2,%Counter%) Do (
:: removing this part makes it work fine
set line=%%C
set /a line+=1
set /a line/=2
:: alternate way doesnt work either
REM set /a line=%line% / 2
:: this part without the math part would be %%C instead of %Line%
echo %line%. !Line_%%C!
)
pause
```

(made an edit)
the second part isnt working for some reason
it just crashes
if i remove the line that does the math it works fine but instead display 1. 3. 5. 7.

version.txt

```
everything
0
minecraft
0
steam
0
obs
0
```

fixed test_list.bat :D

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "num=1"
set "counter=0"
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (version.txt) do (
set /a num+=1
if "!num!"=="2" (set /a counter+=1&set "line_!counter!=%%i"&set num=0)
)

echo.

For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do (echo %%C. !Line_%%C!)

pause
```

Comment: this is the whole script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "num=1"
set "counter=0"
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in (version.txt) do (
    set /a num+=1
    if "!num!"=="2" (set /a counter+=1&set "line_!counter!=%%i"&echo %%i&set num=0)
)

echo.
set line_1
set line_2
set line_3

pause
```

**Would output:**

> everything
>   minecraft
>   steam
>   obs
>   
>   line_1=everything
>   line_2=minecraft
>   line_3=steam

Comment: a wonderful start but i need it to actually save these outputs to !Line_%Counter%!

Comment: i did and btw thanks for the help :D i was stuck trying to figure this out for the longest

Comment: im working on something big and im trying to not hardcode it so its easy to change. so im downloading 1 version.txt that will include the names of programs and their version number :D its hosted at https://github.com/MarioMasta64/EverythingPortable/ (i havent put the program downloader specificly up yet tho)

Comment: just know nothing i do is pretty at first im better at rapid prototyping than code developement lol